# Can I change SORM id type to UUID?

Tags: scala, sorm

Can I change SORM id type to UUID, or can I not?

SORM samples so little from: http://sorm-framework.org/

Where can I see more SORM samples?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find nothing related in the Web today. But I checked the source code that is on https://github.com/sorm/sorm and everything that is related with ID is using Long.

On the core they are using this class  https://github.com/sorm/sorm/blob/master/src/main/scala/sorm/core/Util.scala
to ensure that the id will be converted property to a Long value. In other words this framework seems to be prepared to support it but it's not supporting UUID yet.

Comment: I confirm everything stated.